# How to show a div until closed only once

Tags: javascript

I have a div that can be closed from view using the code below. It works fine, but what I'd like to do is only show the div once so that it doesn't reappear if a visitor closes the div and then visits another page on the site (at which point it currently reappears, then for the visitor to have to close it again).

Could anyone help point out how this is possible? (If possible) it would be good to maybe show the div if a visitor revisits the website in the future, but just to show the div once until closed while the visitor is currently on the site.

```
<div class="fragment">
    <div class="fragment-inner">
        Get 5% off your orders
        <button id="closeButton">close</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('closeButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    }, false); 
</script>
```

Comment: You can use a cookie/webstorage to store the closed state... and on page load based on the cookie/webstorage value hide the element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z56m9v11/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)/[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to keep the state.

The diff is when user open a new tab or close the browser, if you use session storage, the state will not keep, while localStorage will keep the state until you change the value or clear it.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var fragment = document.getElementsByClassName('fragment')[0];
    document.getElementById('closeButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fragment.style.display = 'none';
        sessionStorage.setItem('close', 'close');
    }, false);

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('close') === 'close') {
        fragment.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Right answer, but don´t use if you have to support older browsers (IE).

Comment: Yep, then OP may need to use js-cookie or find some polyfills, anyway, as storages support downto IE8, I believe it cover most cases?

Comment: This is great, thank you. One thing (although small) is that once the div has been closed, when visiting another page on the site the div will appear until the page has fully loaded, at which point the div then disappears. I guess it's because the page needs to load fully before the script comes in to effect (?) but is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Yes, you can use `domready` instead of `window.onload` to wrap the script. Or you can put the scripts at the end of the body, both of them will run when the dom structure is ready while videos/images may not loaded yet.

Comment: As you use pure javascript not `jQuery`, you just have to move the codes inside that window.onload to the end of body, where your origin code places.

Comment: Would something like this work best? (The div still flashes quickly on subsequent page visits after the div has been previously closed however)  `<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var fragment = document.getElementsByClassName('fragment')[0];
    document.getElementById('closeButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fragment.style.display = 'none';
        sessionStorage.setItem('close', 'close');
    }, false);

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('close') === 'close') {
        fragment.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
</script>`

Comment: Does this still flashes?

Comment: Or you can think it reversely, add `style="display:none"` or a class that has the `css` rule with `display:none` to that `fragment`, then only show it when `sessionStorage.getItem('close') !== 'close'`. See the [demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8orkeekv/1/).

Comment: Excellent, this works perfectly and doesn't flash. Thank you very much for your help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
var btn = document.getElementById('closeButton');
btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    sessionStorage.setItem('fragment', 'hidden');
}, false);
if (sessionStorage.getItem('fragment') == 'hidden') {
    btn.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z56m9v11/)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a cookie for this:

```
document.getElementById('closeButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    // set cookie
    setCookie("closed","true", 100); 
}, false);

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Then you can call on every other page the getCookie("closed") function to check if the cookie is set or not.

```
if(!getCookie('closed')){
   // call window again
}
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)